# Issue with PHP not allowing multiple function parameters

Tags: php

is there an issue with PHP not allowing multiple function parameters and returning the correct value. Here is the code:

```
function getConfig($name) {
$sql = "SELECT value FROM config WHERE name = '".$name."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print $row["value"];
} 

getConfig("name");
```

While the code above works, the code bellow similar does not work. Here is the code:

```
function getConfig($name, $from) {
$sql = "SELECT value '".$from."' config WHERE name = '".$name."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print $row["value"];
} 

getConfig("name", "config");
```

Why does that occur that the 1st function works and the second does not?

Comment: This code is terribly insecure.

Comment: It's hard to tell without telling what is being passed in the $from variable

Comment: okk yea i figured....,

Comment: He sends "config" for $from. Look at the last method call. That's the problem. $sql become "SELECT value config config WHERE [...]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT value FROM '".$from."' WHERE name = '".$name."'";
//                   FROM TABLE_NAME
//           and not TABLE_NAME TABLE_NAME
```